# Receiving piped datastream in electron app

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, stderr

I have a Python script generating a datastream on `stderr`. I can run it in the terminal and get the data printed line for line.

I tried to pipe it in my Electron app via `python3 script.py | electron main.js` and expected it to be accessible within my app via

```
process.stderr.on('readable', (chunk) => {
  console.log(process.stderr.read())
  console.log(`Chunk:- ${chunk}`);
});
```

But it is `null` and `undefined`. Is this the wrong way?

Comment: Did you get your problem sorted out? If yes, you can mark an answer as accepted to indicate so.

Answer (score 0):

The [`readable`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_readable) event handler is not passed an argument. The following code is adapted from the Node documentation on [`readable.read()`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_read_size):

```
process.stderr.on('readable', () => {
  let chunk;

  // Use a loop to make sure we read all currently available data
  while (null !== (chunk = process.stderr.read())) {
    console.log(`Chunk:- ${chunk}`);
  }
});
```